# Python UTF-8 encoded on PC, UnicodeDecodeError on Mac

Tags: python, macos, encoding, utf-8

I wrote a script to create a text file on a PC, and it uses these types of commands to open and write it:

```
newfile = open(r'tweettext.txt','w')
```

`print("\n"+tweet,end=',',file=newfile)`

And `sys.getdefaultencoding()` reveals 'utf-8' encoding. But when I tried to open this text file in IDLE on a Mac with:

```
with open('tweettext.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    tweetlist = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

I received this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 2135: invalid start byte
```

The PC has Python 3.5.1 and Mac has 3.5.2. How can I open this file on the Mac, and how can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: How did you open `newfile` and how are you opening the file on Mac? Is this Python 3?

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for helping. I have updated this info in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` only applies to `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdin`.

You opened your file you print to without an encoding set, so the default *for files* is used, which is whatever the [`locale.getpreferredlocale()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns (see the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), under *encoding*).

Set it explicitly instead:

```
newfile = open(r'tweettext.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```